# GZip Decompression Gives Blank File

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream

Given the code below, why is the decompression not working? "NewFile2.txt" should have the original, decompressed text, but the file is just blank.

```
ioTests.CompressFile(@"c:\newfile.txt", @"c:\newfile.txt.gz");
ioTests.DecompressFile(@"c:\newfile.txt.gz", @"c:\newfile2.txt");

public void CompressFile(string inFileName, string outFileName)
{
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream outFile = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create);

    GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress);

    int theByte = inFile.ReadByte();

    while (theByte != -1)
    {
        compStream.WriteByte((byte)theByte);
        theByte = inFile.ReadByte();
    }

    compStream.Close();
}

public void DecompressFile(string inFileName, string outFileName)
{
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream outFile = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.CreateNew);

    GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress);

    int theByte = compStream.ReadByte();

    while (theByte != -1)
    {
        outFile.WriteByte((byte)theByte);

        theByte = compStream.ReadByte();
    }

    compStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing decompressed file to the "outFile" ?

Comment: @ssg: Yeah that's what I'm doing (I think). The outfile is the one `WriteByte`ing from the (now) uncompressed compstream byte (held in `theByte`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outFile.Flush(); // after your loop
```

Comment: You're my favorite dude tonight! Thanks! That worked! (I'm such an idiot for not seeing that. I was going cross-eyed)

Comment: @Richard : LoL, we all do such kind of crap when doing night coding :P

Answer (score 2):

I prefer

```
outFile.Close()
```

as that flushes the stream and calls the Dispose method, releasing allocated resources.

Comment: That is actually what I did instead. But Waleed was right that the stream wasn't flushing.

Answer (score 2):

Since the streams you use implement the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), you should `Dispose()` / `Close()` your classes, or use the `using` statement to do this automatically:

```
    using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create))

    using (GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress)) {

        int theByte = inFile.ReadByte();
        // ... Rest of your code

    }
```

This roughly translates to:

```
    try {
       FileStream inFile = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open);
       FileStream outFile = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create);
       GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress);

        int theByte = inFile.ReadByte();
        // ... Rest of your code

    } finally {
        if (inFile != null) inFile.Dispose();
        if (outFile != null) outFile.Dispose();
        if (compStream != null) compStream.Dispose();
    }
```